# How to get a count of characters until certain character C#

Tags: c#, count, substring, string-length

I'm trying to get the full path of a string as follow:

```
ksh /u01/Utilities/SSL_Certificates/TestCert_20170724.sh
```

but I'm having an issue and I'm getting

```
/u01/Utilities/SSL_Certificates/Tes
```

that's because is getting the 4 characters from `ksh`

how can I get the count starting from 0 to the first index of "/"

What I have is this:

```
string SSL_configuration_Path = ShellCommand.Substring(ShellCommand.IndexOf("/"), ShellCommand.LastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: This is why it usually helps to check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter is how many characters.

Not which character is the last.

```
string SSL_configuration_Path = ShellCommand.Substring(
  ShellCommand.IndexOf("/"),
  ShellCommand.LastIndexOf("/") - ShellCommand.IndexOf("/"));
```

Not that this is a good solution, but it should explain what you're doing wrong and why it didn't work.

Comment: Now I'm getting `/u01/Utilities/SSL_Certificates/TestCer`

Comment: 2nd param is length?  Then shouldn't you have a subtract symbol instead of plus?  And switch the terms?  Like this: `ShellCommand.LastIndexOf("/") - ShellCommand.IndexOf("/")`

Comment: You're correct, I just substract and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Parh` class which is specially designed for working with directories' and files' names:

```
string ShellCommand = "ksh /u01/Utilities/SSL_Certificates/TestCert_20170724.sh";

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(ShellCommand
  .Substring(line.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 
     Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, 
     Path.DirectorySeparatorChar })));

Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Outcome:

```
\u01\Utilities\SSL_Certificates
```

please, notice that you can use either `/` or `\` as direcory separators and get the final result normalized (i.e. with `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` seperator)